# Написать цикла для перебора символов в нескольких строчках

Tags: python, циклы

Дано N строк, нужно написать цикл так, чтобы перебрать каждый символ в каждой строке. Понимаю, что нужен вложенный цикл, чтобы сначала пройтись по количеству строк, а потом по каждой строке отдельно, но не понимаю как записать - на вложенном цикле, где я хочу пройти по длине строки выдает ошибку `string indices must be integers`. В строки могут входить как цифры, так и пробелы и буквы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
n = int(input())
arr = [input().split() for i in range(0, n)]

for elm in arr:
    for p in ''.join(elm):
        print(p)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
N = int(input())  # количество строк
strings_arr = []

for string in range(N):
    strings_arr.append(str(input()))  # ввод строки и добавление ее в список
    
for string in strings_arr:  # проходимся по строкам в словаре
    for letter in string:  # проходимся по буквам в строке
        print(letter)  # выводим букву
```

Comment: `input()` и так всегда выдаёт строки - зачем дополнительно в строки переводить?

Comment: если использовать `join()`, то не потребуется делать 2 цикла